# how do i select OK to terms of service on xterm while upgrading

Tags: apt, upgrade, xterm, intel

`apt upgrade` process stalls at 8 percent when Intel wireless terms of service appears and requests confirmation of agreement with an `OK` at the bottom. I am new and trying to learn, but I'm stuck. I can't select or input anything in order to select the `OK`.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting tab and then enter.

When you hit tab that should select the "OK" and then hitting Enter should get you past that.  You may need to hit tab twice.